# cannot import matplotlib.pylab with matplotlib installed

Tags: matplotlib

I understand that there have been several questions asked on this topic, however, I didn't find them able to solve my problem.

I installed matplotlib on the maching under /python-path/site-packages, both library and python are 64bits,

so I could import matplotlib no problem, but when I tried to import matplotlib.pylab or pylab, it gives me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shownet.py", line 40, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pylab
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 247, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 78, in <module>
    new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, show = pylab_setup()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 25, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkagg.py", line 10, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import gtk, FigureManagerGTK, FigureCanvasGTK,\
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 8, in <module>
    import gtk; gdk = gtk.gdk
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    _init()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 52, in _init
    _gtk.init_check()
```

Would anyone know why this is so?

Also this is on linux, and I built it using setup.py

Comment: It looks like your backtrace is missing a few lines (as it does not include the actual exception being raised).  Given that it looks like it is raising out of gtk, I would make sure that gtk (and it's supporting python packages) are correctly installed.

Comment: It seems like you are missing GTK libraries. Which Linux or OS are you using?

Comment: Hi, the version I'm using is Linux version 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64, I just want to mention that importing the standard python libraries such as numpy works fine, I'm new to python and I'm not sure if that's an indication that the python package supports are working fine?

Comment: In terms of the backtrace...that's all i've got from command window. I also included the matplotlib path in sys.path, but it doesn't seem to help either..